# How to write a transformer in codable?

Tags: ios, swift, codable

Let's consider a scenario where I want to populate model in `Codable` as below.

```
struct SampleModel: Codable {
    let showId: String
}
```

The response that we receive from the server is 'showId : "one".' However, I want to save it as 'First' instead of 'one'.

Is there any way to do with `Codable` ?

Comment: create lookup and do manual decoding

Comment: Using just Codable, no. In fact, most of what you want to do will not involve Codable, but string manipulation. For now, I would just ignore the Codable part and figure out how to map `one` to `first`, `two` to `second`, and so on.

Comment: I worked with mantle framework where we could write transformer to change the value, If it was a class then maybe overriding setter method would have worked. .@CalebKleveter , I have very less input set, till 10 only, I can do that just by creating a dictionary (hashmap for other languages.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you correctly

```
struct SampleModel: Codable {
    let showId: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case showId
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        do {

            let id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .showId)
            let stored = id == "one" ? "First" : "default"
            self.init(showId:stored)

        } catch {
            print(error)
            throw error
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly I wanted.